Toeplitz conjecture in a special case: state of the art question
I recently discovered the Toeplitz conjecture that I recall below.

Conjecture Does every Jordan curve contains the vertices of a square ?

On the Wikipdia page, some special cases have been proved. My question is about the following case:

If there exists a point $x_0$ inside the Jordan curve such that every point of this curve is uniquely determined by the angle bewteen the $x$-axis and the vector linking $x_0$ and the point, is the Toeplitz conjecture already proved in this case ?

I detail this special case with two drawings.
Case 1 satisfying the special case

Case 2 not satisfying the property

Thank you very much!

https://www.ams.org/journals/notices/201404/rnoti-p346.pdf

Thank you for this link @WillJagy !
